# Is there a simple way to memorize/reason out the solubility rules?

Tags: solubility

Normally, to determine if a compound is soluble, I would just apply the solubility rules, which can be found [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Solubilty/Solubility_Rules).

The problem is, these are not fun to memorize as there are often loads of exceptions for each ion. Also, they are easy to forget. Is there an alternative way to reason out if something is soluble or not?

I was thinking that lattice energy might be a factor in determining whether or not something is soluble or not because if the lattice energy is low, the ionic compound can easily break apart and form ions. Thus, if the charges are low, it should be soluble. However, this hypothesis doesn't really explain why fluoride and hydroxide salts are insoluble.

Comment: Lattice energy surely is a factor, but there are no easy ways to memorize or derive it either.